# Assert C/C++ on LuaSQL code

Tags: c++, c, lua, luasql

I´d like to know what happens on this code, taken from the LuaSQL code (It´s on the LuaSQL source - file ls_OCI8.c).

I want to understand what this piece of code does (to be more specific: I want to understand what the ASSERT function is doing). As far as I know, the assert standard function is: void assert(int expression). It does not have three parameters.

```
ASSERT (L, OCIParamGet (cur->stmthp, OCI_HTYPE_STMT, cur->errhp,
        (dvoid **)&param, i), cur->errhp);
ASSERT (L, OCIAttrGet (param, OCI_DTYPE_PARAM,
        (dvoid *)&(name), (ub4 *)&(col->namelen),
        OCI_ATTR_NAME, cur->errhp), cur->errhp);
    copy_column_name (col, name);
ASSERT (L, OCIAttrGet (param, OCI_DTYPE_PARAM,
        (dvoid *)&(col->type), (ub4 *)0, OCI_ATTR_DATA_TYPE,
        cur->errhp), cur->errhp);
```

The entire source code is:

```
/*
** LuaSQL, Oracle driver
** Authors: Tomas Guisasola, Leonardo Godinho
** See Copyright Notice in license.html
** $Id: ls_oci8.c,v 1.31 2009/02/07 23:16:23 tomas Exp $
*/

#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#include "oci.h"
#include "oratypes.h"
#include "ociapr.h"
#include "ocidem.h"

#include "lua.h"
#include "lauxlib.h"

#include "luasql.h"

#define LUASQL_ENVIRONMENT_OCI8 "Oracle environment"
#define LUASQL_CONNECTION_OCI8 "Oracle connection"
#define LUASQL_CURSOR_OCI8 "Oracle cursor"


typedef struct {
    short         closed;
    int           conn_counter;
    OCIEnv       *envhp;
    OCIError     *errhp; /* !!! */
} env_data;


typedef struct {
    short         closed;
    short         loggedon;
    short         auto_commit;        /* 0 for manual commit */
    int           cur_counter;
    int           env;                /* reference to environment */
    OCISvcCtx    *svchp;              /* service handle */
    OCIError     *errhp; /* !!! */
} conn_data;


typedef union {
    int     i;
    char   *s;
    double  d;
} column_value;


typedef struct {
    ub2           type;    /* database type */
    text         *name;    /* column name */
    ub4           namelen; /* column name length */
    ub2           max;     /* maximum size */
    sb2           null;    /* is null? */
    OCIDefine    *define;  /* define handle */
    column_value  val;
} column_data;


typedef struct {
    short         closed;
    int           conn;               /* reference to connection */
    int           numcols;            /* number of columns */
    int           colnames, coltypes; /* reference to column info tables */
    int           curr_tuple;         /* next tuple to be read */
    char         *text;               /* text of SQL statement */
    OCIStmt      *stmthp;             /* statement handle */
    OCIError     *errhp; /* !!! */
    column_data  *cols;               /* array of columns */
} cur_data;


int checkerr (lua_State *L, sword status, OCIError *errhp);
#define ASSERT(L,exp,err) {sword s = exp; if (s) return checkerr (L, s, err);}
LUASQL_API int luaopen_luasql_oci8 (lua_State *L);


/*
** Check for valid environment.
*/
static env_data *getenvironment (lua_State *L) {
    env_data *env = (env_data *)luaL_checkudata (L, 1, LUASQL_ENVIRONMENT_OCI8);
    luaL_argcheck (L, env != NULL, 1, LUASQL_PREFIX"environment expected");
    luaL_argcheck (L, !env->closed, 1, LUASQL_PREFIX"environment is closed");
    return env;
}


/*
** Check for valid connection.
*/
static conn_data *getconnection (lua_State *L) {
    conn_data *conn = (conn_data *)luaL_checkudata (L, 1, LUASQL_CONNECTION_OCI8);
    luaL_argcheck (L, conn != NULL, 1, LUASQL_PREFIX"connection expected");
    luaL_argcheck (L, !conn->closed, 1, LUASQL_PREFIX"connection is closed");
    return conn;
}


/*
** Check for valid cursor.
*/
static cur_data *getcursor (lua_State *L) {
    cur_data *cur = (cur_data *)luaL_checkudata (L, 1, LUASQL_CURSOR_OCI8);
    luaL_argcheck (L, cur != NULL, 1, LUASQL_PREFIX"cursor expected");
    luaL_argcheck (L, !cur->closed, 1, LUASQL_PREFIX"cursor is closed");
    return cur;
}


/*
** Push nil plus an error message.
*/
int checkerr (lua_State *L, sword status, OCIError *errhp) {
    lua_pushnil (L);
    switch (status) {
        case OCI_SUCCESS:
            lua_pushnil (L); /* !!!!!!!!!!!!! */
            break;
        case OCI_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO:
            lua_pushstring (L, LUASQL_PREFIX"Success with info!");
            break;
        case OCI_NEED_DATA:
            lua_pushstring (L, LUASQL_PREFIX"OCI_NEED_DATA");
            break;
        case OCI_NO_DATA:
            lua_pushstring (L, LUASQL_PREFIX"OCI_NODATA");
            break;
        case OCI_ERROR: {
            text errbuf[512];
            sb4 errcode = 0;
            OCIErrorGet (errhp, (ub4) 1, (text *) NULL, &errcode,
                errbuf, (ub4) sizeof (errbuf), OCI_HTYPE_ERROR);
            lua_pushstring (L, LUASQL_PREFIX);
            lua_pushstring (L, errbuf);
            lua_concat (L, 2);
            break;
        }
        case OCI_INVALID_HANDLE:
            lua_pushstring (L, LUASQL_PREFIX"OCI_INVALID_HANDLE");
            break;
        case OCI_STILL_EXECUTING:
            lua_pushstring (L, LUASQL_PREFIX"OCI_STILL_EXECUTE");
            break;
        case OCI_CONTINUE:
            lua_pushstring (L, LUASQL_PREFIX"OCI_CONTINUE");
            break;
    }
    return 2;
}


/*
** Copy the column name to the column structure and convert it to lower case.
*/
static void copy_column_name (column_data *col, text *name) {
    unsigned int i;
    col->name = (text *)malloc (col->namelen);
    memcpy (col->name, name, col->namelen);
    for (i = 0; i < col->namelen; i++)
        col->name[i] = tolower (col->name[i]);
}


/*
** Alloc buffers for column values.
*/
static int alloc_column_buffer (lua_State *L, cur_data *cur, int i) {
    /* column index ranges from 1 to numcols */
    /* C array index ranges from 0 to numcols-1 */
    column_data *col = &(cur->cols[i-1]);
    OCIParam *param;
    text *name;

    ASSERT (L, OCIParamGet (cur->stmthp, OCI_HTYPE_STMT, cur->errhp,
        (dvoid **)&param, i), cur->errhp);
    ASSERT (L, OCIAttrGet (param, OCI_DTYPE_PARAM,
        (dvoid *)&(name), (ub4 *)&(col->namelen),
        OCI_ATTR_NAME, cur->errhp), cur->errhp);
    copy_column_name (col, name);
    ASSERT (L, OCIAttrGet (param, OCI_DTYPE_PARAM,
        (dvoid *)&(col->type), (ub4 *)0, OCI_ATTR_DATA_TYPE,
        cur->errhp), cur->errhp);

    switch (col->type) {
        case SQLT_CHR:
        case SQLT_STR:
        case SQLT_VCS:
        case SQLT_AFC:
        case SQLT_AVC:
            ASSERT (L, OCIAttrGet (param, OCI_DTYPE_PARAM,
                (dvoid *)&(col->max), 0, OCI_ATTR_DATA_SIZE,
                cur->errhp), cur->errhp);
            col->val.s = calloc (col->max + 1, sizeof(col->val.s));
            ASSERT (L, OCIDefineByPos (cur->stmthp, &(col->define),
                cur->errhp, (ub4)i, col->val.s, col->max+1,
                SQLT_STR /*col->type*/, (dvoid *)&(col->null), (ub2 *)0,
                (ub2 *)0, (ub4) OCI_DEFAULT), cur->errhp);
            break;
        case SQLT_NUM:
        case SQLT_FLT:
        case SQLT_INT:
        /* case SQLT_UIN: */
            ASSERT (L, OCIDefineByPos (cur->stmthp, &(col->define),
                cur->errhp, (ub4)i, &(col->val.d), sizeof(col->val.d),
                SQLT_FLT, (dvoid *)&(col->null), (ub2 *)0,
                (ub2 *)0, (ub4) OCI_DEFAULT), cur->errhp);
            break;
        case SQLT_CLOB: {
            env_data *env;
            conn_data *conn;
            lua_rawgeti (L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX, cur->conn);
            conn = (conn_data *)lua_touserdata (L, -1);
            lua_rawgeti (L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX, conn->env);
            env = (env_data *)lua_touserdata (L, -1);
            lua_pop (L, 2);
            ASSERT (L, OCIDescriptorAlloc (env->envhp, (dvoid *)&(col->val.s),
                OCI_DTYPE_LOB, (size_t)0, (dvoid **)0), cur->errhp);
            ASSERT (L, OCIDefineByPos (cur->stmthp, &(col->define),
                cur->errhp, (ub4)i, &(col->val.s), (sb4)sizeof(dvoid *),
                SQLT_CLOB, (dvoid *)&(col->null), (ub2 *)0, (ub2 *)0,
                OCI_DEFAULT), cur->errhp);
            break;
        }
        default:
            luaL_error (L, LUASQL_PREFIX"invalid type %d #%d", col->type, i);
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}


/*
** Deallocate column buffers.
*/
static int free_column_buffers (lua_State *L, cur_data *cur, int i) {
    /* column index ranges from 1 to numcols */
    /* C array index ranges from 0 to numcols-1 */
    column_data *col = &(cur->cols[i-1]);
    free (col->name);
    switch (col->type) {
        case SQLT_INT:
        case SQLT_FLT:
        case SQLT_NUM:
            break;
        case SQLT_CHR:
        case SQLT_STR:
        case SQLT_VCS:
        case SQLT_AFC:
        case SQLT_AVC:
            free(col->val.s);
            break;
        case SQLT_CLOB:
            ASSERT (L, OCIDescriptorFree (col->val.s,
                OCI_DTYPE_LOB), cur->errhp);
            break;
        default:
            luaL_error (L, LUASQL_PREFIX"unknown type");
            /*printf("free_buffers(): Unknow Type: %d count: %d\n",cols.item[count].type, count );*/
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}


/*
** Push a value on top of the stack.
*/
static int pushvalue (lua_State *L, cur_data *cur, int i) {
    /* column index ranges from 1 to numcols */
    /* C array index ranges from 0 to numcols-1 */
    column_data *col = &(cur->cols[i-1]);
    if (col->null) {
        /* Oracle NULL => Lua nil */
        lua_pushnil (L);
        return 1;
    }
    switch (col->type) {
        case SQLT_NUM:
        case SQLT_INT:
        case SQLT_FLT:
            lua_pushnumber (L, col->val.d);
            break;
        case SQLT_CHR:
        case SQLT_STR:
        case SQLT_VCS:
        case SQLT_AFC:
        case SQLT_AVC:
            lua_pushstring (L, (char *)(col->val.s));
            break;
        case SQLT_CLOB: {
            ub4 lob_len;
            conn_data *conn;
            env_data *env;
            lua_rawgeti (L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX, cur->conn);
            conn = lua_touserdata (L, -1);
            lua_rawgeti (L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX, conn->env);
            env = lua_touserdata (L, -1);
            lua_pop (L, 2);
            ASSERT (L, OCILobGetLength (conn->svchp, cur->errhp,
                (OCILobLocator *)col->val.s, &lob_len), cur->errhp);
            if (lob_len > 0) {
                char *lob_buffer=malloc(lob_len);
                ub4 amount = lob_len;

                ASSERT(L, OCILobRead(conn->svchp, cur->errhp,
                    (OCILobLocator *) col->val.s, &amount, (ub4) 1,
                    (dvoid *) lob_buffer, (ub4) lob_len, (dvoid *)0,
                    (sb4 (*) (dvoid *, CONST dvoid *, ub4, ub1)) 0,
                    (ub2) 0, (ub1) SQLCS_IMPLICIT), cur->errhp);
                lua_pushlstring (L, lob_buffer, amount);
                free(lob_buffer);
            } else {
                lua_pushstring (L, "");
            }
            break;
        }
        default:
            luaL_error (L, LUASQL_PREFIX"unexpected error");
    }
    return 1;
}


/*
** Get another row of the given cursor.
*/
static int cur_fetch (lua_State *L) {
    cur_data *cur = getcursor (L);
    sword status = OCIStmtFetch (cur->stmthp, cur->errhp, 1,
        OCI_FETCH_NEXT, OCI_DEFAULT);

    if (status == OCI_NO_DATA) {
        /* No more rows */
        lua_pushnil (L);
        return 1;
    } else if (status != OCI_SUCCESS) {
        /* Error */
        return checkerr (L, status, cur->errhp);
    }

    if (lua_istable (L, 2)) {
        int i;
        const char *opts = luaL_optstring (L, 3, "n");
        if (strchr (opts, 'n') != NULL)
            /* Copy values to numerical indices */
            for (i = 1; i <= cur->numcols; i++) {
                int ret = pushvalue (L, cur, i);
                if (ret != 1)
                    return ret;
                lua_rawseti (L, 2, i);
            }
        if (strchr (opts, 'a') != NULL)
            /* Copy values to alphanumerical indices */
            for (i = 1; i <= cur->numcols; i++) {
                column_data *col = &(cur->cols[i-1]);
                int ret;
                lua_pushlstring (L, col->name, col->namelen);
                if ((ret = pushvalue (L, cur, i)) != 1)
                    return ret;
                lua_rawset (L, 2);
            }
        lua_pushvalue(L, 2);
        return 1; /* return table */
    }
    else {
        int i;
        luaL_checkstack (L, cur->numcols, LUASQL_PREFIX"too many columns");
        for (i = 1; i <= cur->numcols; i++) {
            int ret = pushvalue (L, cur, i);
            if (ret != 1)
                return ret;
        }
        return cur->numcols; /* return #numcols values */
    }
}


/*
** Close the cursor on top of the stack.
** Return 1
*/
static int cur_close (lua_State *L) {
    int i;
    conn_data *conn;
    cur_data *cur = (cur_data *)luaL_checkudata (L, 1, LUASQL_CURSOR_OCI8);
    luaL_argcheck (L, cur != NULL, 1, LUASQL_PREFIX"cursor expected");
    if (cur->closed) {
        lua_pushboolean (L, 0);
        return 1;
    }

    /* Deallocate buffers. */
    for (i = 1; i <= cur->numcols; i++) {
        int ret = free_column_buffers (L, cur, i);
        if (ret)
            return ret;
    }
    free (cur->cols);
    free (cur->text);

    /* Nullify structure fields. */
    cur->closed = 1;
    if (cur->stmthp)
        OCIHandleFree ((dvoid *)cur->stmthp, OCI_HTYPE_STMT);
    if (cur->errhp)
        OCIHandleFree ((dvoid *)cur->errhp, OCI_HTYPE_ERROR);
    /* Decrement cursor counter on connection object */
    lua_rawgeti (L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX, cur->conn);
    conn = lua_touserdata (L, -1);
    conn->cur_counter--;
    luaL_unref (L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX, cur->conn);
    luaL_unref (L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX, cur->colnames);
    luaL_unref (L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX, cur->coltypes);

    lua_pushboolean (L, 1);
    return 1;
}


/*
** Return the list of field names as a table on top of the stack.
*/
static int cur_getcolnames (lua_State *L) {
    cur_data *cur = getcursor (L);
    if (cur->colnames != LUA_NOREF)
        lua_rawgeti (L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX, cur->colnames);
    else {
        int i;
        lua_newtable (L);
        for (i = 1; i <= cur->numcols; i++) {
            column_data *col = &(cur->cols[i-1]);
            lua_pushlstring (L, col->name, col->namelen);
            lua_rawseti (L, -2, i);
        }
        lua_pushvalue (L, -1);
        cur->colnames = luaL_ref (L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX);
    }
    return 1;
}


/*
**
*/
static char *getcolumntype (column_data *col) {
    switch (col->type) {
        case SQLT_CHR:
        case SQLT_STR:
        case SQLT_VCS:
        case SQLT_AFC:
        case SQLT_AVC:
            return "string";
        case SQLT_NUM:
        case SQLT_FLT:
        case SQLT_INT:
        /* case SQLT_UIN: */
            return "number";
        case SQLT_CLOB:
            return "string";
        default:
            return "";
    }
}


/*
** Return the list of field types as a table on top of the stack.
*/
static int cur_getcoltypes (lua_State *L) {
    cur_data *cur = getcursor (L);
    if (cur->coltypes != LUA_NOREF)
        lua_rawgeti (L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX, cur->coltypes);
    else {
        int i;
        lua_newtable (L);
        for (i = 1; i <= cur->numcols; i++) {
            column_data *col = &(cur->cols[i-1]);
            lua_pushnumber (L, i);
            lua_pushstring (L, getcolumntype (col));
            lua_rawset (L, -3);
        }
        lua_pushvalue (L, -1);
        cur->coltypes = luaL_ref (L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX);
    }
    return 1;
}


/*
** Push the number of rows.
*/
static int cur_numrows (lua_State *L) {
    int n;
    cur_data *cur = getcursor (L);
    ASSERT (L, OCIAttrGet ((dvoid *) cur->stmthp, OCI_HTYPE_STMT, (dvoid *)&n,
        (ub4)0, OCI_ATTR_NUM_ROWS, cur->errhp), cur->errhp);
    lua_pushnumber (L, n);
    return 1;
}


/*
** Close a Connection object.
*/
static int conn_close (lua_State *L) {
    env_data *env;
    conn_data *conn = (conn_data *)luaL_checkudata (L, 1, LUASQL_CONNECTION_OCI8);
    luaL_argcheck (L, conn != NULL, 1, LUASQL_PREFIX"connection expected");
    if (conn->closed) {
        lua_pushboolean (L, 0);
        return 1;
    }
    if (conn->cur_counter > 0)
        return luaL_error (L, LUASQL_PREFIX"there are open cursors");

    /* Nullify structure fields. */
    conn->closed = 1;
    if (conn->svchp) {
        if (conn->loggedon)
            OCILogoff (conn->svchp, conn->errhp);
        else
            OCIHandleFree ((dvoid *)conn->svchp, OCI_HTYPE_SVCCTX);
    }
    if (conn->errhp)
        OCIHandleFree ((dvoid *)conn->errhp, OCI_HTYPE_ERROR);
    /* Decrement connection counter on environment object */
    lua_rawgeti (L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX, conn->env);
    env = lua_touserdata (L, -1);
    env->conn_counter--;
    luaL_unref (L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX, conn->env);

    lua_pushboolean (L, 1);
    return 1;
}


/*
** Create a new Cursor object and push it on top of the stack.
*/
static int create_cursor (lua_State *L, int o, conn_data *conn, OCIStmt *stmt, const char *text) {
    int i;
    env_data *env;
    cur_data *cur = (cur_data *)lua_newuserdata(L, sizeof(cur_data));
    luasql_setmeta (L, LUASQL_CURSOR_OCI8);

    conn->cur_counter++;
    /* fill in structure */
    cur->closed = 0;
    cur->numcols = 0;
    cur->colnames = LUA_NOREF;
    cur->coltypes = LUA_NOREF;
    cur->curr_tuple = 0;
    cur->stmthp = stmt;
    cur->errhp = NULL;
    cur->cols = NULL;
    cur->text = strdup (text);
    lua_pushvalue (L, o);
    cur->conn = luaL_ref (L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX);

    /* error handler */
    lua_rawgeti (L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX, conn->env);
    env = lua_touserdata (L, -1);
    lua_pop (L, 1);
    ASSERT (L, OCIHandleAlloc((dvoid *) env->envhp,
        (dvoid **) &(cur->errhp), (ub4) OCI_HTYPE_ERROR, (size_t) 0,
        (dvoid **) 0), conn->errhp);
    /* get number of columns */
    ASSERT (L, OCIAttrGet ((dvoid *)stmt, (ub4)OCI_HTYPE_STMT,
        (dvoid *)&cur->numcols, (ub4 *)0, (ub4)OCI_ATTR_PARAM_COUNT,
        cur->errhp), cur->errhp);
    cur->cols = (column_data *)malloc (sizeof(column_data) * cur->numcols);
    /* define output variables */
    /* Oracle and Lua column indices ranges from 1 to numcols */
    /* C array indices ranges from 0 to numcols-1 */
    for (i = 1; i <= cur->numcols; i++) {
        int ret = alloc_column_buffer (L, cur, i);
        if (ret)
            return ret;
    }

    return 1;
}


/*
** Execute an SQL statement.
** Return a Cursor object if the statement is a query, otherwise
** return the number of tuples affected by the statement.
*/
static int conn_execute (lua_State *L) {
    env_data *env;
    conn_data *conn = getconnection (L);
    const char *statement = luaL_checkstring (L, 2);
    sword status;
    ub4 prefetch = 0;
    ub4 iters;
    ub4 mode;
    ub2 type;
    OCIStmt *stmthp;

    /* get environment */
    lua_rawgeti (L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX, conn->env);
    if (!lua_isuserdata (L, -1))
        luaL_error(L,LUASQL_PREFIX"invalid environment in connection!");
    env = (env_data *)lua_touserdata (L, -1);
    /* statement handle */
    ASSERT (L, OCIHandleAlloc ((dvoid *)env->envhp, (dvoid **)&stmthp,
        OCI_HTYPE_STMT, (size_t)0, (dvoid **)0), conn->errhp);
    ASSERT (L, OCIAttrSet ((dvoid *)stmthp, (ub4)OCI_HTYPE_STMT,
        (dvoid *)&prefetch, (ub4)0, (ub4)OCI_ATTR_PREFETCH_ROWS,
        conn->errhp), conn->errhp);
    ASSERT (L, OCIStmtPrepare (stmthp, conn->errhp, (text *)statement,
        (ub4) strlen(statement), (ub4) OCI_NTV_SYNTAX, (ub4) OCI_DEFAULT),
        conn->errhp);
    /* statement type */
    ASSERT (L, OCIAttrGet ((dvoid *)stmthp, (ub4) OCI_HTYPE_STMT,
        (dvoid *)&type, (ub4 *)0, (ub4)OCI_ATTR_STMT_TYPE, conn->errhp),
        conn->errhp);
    if (type == OCI_STMT_SELECT)
        iters = 0;
    else
        iters = 1;
    if (conn->auto_commit)
        mode = OCI_COMMIT_ON_SUCCESS;
    else
        mode = OCI_DEFAULT;
    /* execute statement */
    status = OCIStmtExecute (conn->svchp, stmthp, conn->errhp, iters,
        (ub4)0, (CONST OCISnapshot *)NULL, (OCISnapshot *)NULL, mode);
    if (status && (status != OCI_NO_DATA)) {
        OCIHandleFree ((dvoid *)stmthp, OCI_HTYPE_STMT);
        return checkerr (L, status, conn->errhp);
    }
    if (type == OCI_STMT_SELECT) {
        /* create cursor */
        return create_cursor (L, 1, conn, stmthp, statement);
    } else {
        /* return number of rows */
        int rows_affected;
        ASSERT (L, OCIAttrGet ((dvoid *)stmthp, (ub4)OCI_HTYPE_STMT,
            (dvoid *)&rows_affected, (ub4 *)0,
            (ub4)OCI_ATTR_ROW_COUNT, conn->errhp), conn->errhp);
        OCIHandleFree ((dvoid *)stmthp, OCI_HTYPE_STMT);
        lua_pushnumber (L, rows_affected);
        return 1;
    }
}


/*
** Commit the current transaction.
*/
static int conn_commit (lua_State *L) {
    conn_data *conn = getconnection (L);
    ASSERT (L, OCITransCommit (conn->svchp, conn->errhp, OCI_DEFAULT),
        conn->errhp);
/*
    if (conn->auto_commit == 0) 
        ASSERT (L, OCITransStart (conn->svchp, conn->errhp...
*/
    return 0;
}


/*
** Rollback the current transaction.
*/
static int conn_rollback (lua_State *L) {
    conn_data *conn = getconnection (L);
    ASSERT (L, OCITransRollback (conn->svchp, conn->errhp, OCI_DEFAULT),
        conn->errhp);
/*
    if (conn->auto_commit == 0) 
        sql_begin(conn); 
*/
    return 0;
}


/*
** Set "auto commit" property of the connection.
** If 'true', then rollback current transaction.
** If 'false', then start a new transaction.
*/
static int conn_setautocommit (lua_State *L) {
    conn_data *conn = getconnection (L);
    if (lua_toboolean (L, 2)) {
        conn->auto_commit = 1;
        /* Undo active transaction. */
        ASSERT (L, OCITransRollback (conn->svchp, conn->errhp,
            OCI_DEFAULT), conn->errhp);
    }
    else {
        conn->auto_commit = 0;
        /* sql_begin(conn);*/
    }
    lua_pushboolean(L, 1);
    return 1;
}


/*
** Connects to a data source.
*/
static int env_connect (lua_State *L) {
    env_data *env = getenvironment (L);
    const char *sourcename = luaL_checkstring(L, 2);
    const char *username = luaL_optstring(L, 3, NULL);
    const char *password = luaL_optstring(L, 4, NULL);
    /* Sizes of strings */
    size_t snlen = strlen(sourcename);
    size_t userlen = (username) ? strlen(username) : 0;
    size_t passlen = (password) ? strlen(password) : 0;
    /* Alloc connection object */
    conn_data *conn = (conn_data *)lua_newuserdata(L, sizeof(conn_data));

    /* fill in structure */
    luasql_setmeta (L, LUASQL_CONNECTION_OCI8);
    conn->env = LUA_NOREF;
    conn->closed = 1;
    conn->auto_commit = 1;
    conn->cur_counter = 0;
    conn->loggedon = 0;
    conn->svchp = NULL;
    conn->errhp = NULL;
    lua_pushvalue (L, 1);
    conn->env = luaL_ref (L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX);

    /* error handler */
    ASSERT (L, OCIHandleAlloc((dvoid *) env->envhp,
        (dvoid **) &(conn->errhp), /* !!! */
        (ub4) OCI_HTYPE_ERROR, (size_t) 0, (dvoid **) 0), env->errhp);
    /* service handler */
    /*ASSERT (L, OCIHandleAlloc((dvoid *) env->envhp,
        (dvoid **) &(conn->svchp),
        (ub4) OCI_HTYPE_SVCCTX, (size_t) 0, (dvoid **) 0), conn->errhp);
*/
    /* login */
    ASSERT (L, OCILogon(env->envhp, conn->errhp, &(conn->svchp),
        (CONST text*)username, userlen,
        (CONST text*)password, passlen,
        (CONST text*)sourcename, snlen), conn->errhp);
    conn->closed = 0;
    env->conn_counter++;
    conn->loggedon = 1;

    return 1;
}


/*
** Close environment object.
*/
static int env_close (lua_State *L) {
    env_data *env = (env_data *)luaL_checkudata (L, 1, LUASQL_ENVIRONMENT_OCI8);
    luaL_argcheck (L, env != NULL, 1, LUASQL_PREFIX"environment expected");
    if (env->closed) {
        lua_pushboolean (L, 0);
        return 1;
    }
    if (env->conn_counter > 0)
        return luaL_error (L, LUASQL_PREFIX"there are open connections");

    env->closed = 1;
    /* desalocar: env->errhp e env->envhp */
    if (env->envhp)
        OCIHandleFree ((dvoid *)env->envhp, OCI_HTYPE_ENV);
    if (env->errhp)
        OCIHandleFree ((dvoid *)env->errhp, OCI_HTYPE_ERROR);
    lua_pushboolean (L, 1);
    return 1;
}


/*
** Creates an Environment and returns it.
*/
static int create_environment (lua_State *L) {
    env_data *env = (env_data *)lua_newuserdata(L, sizeof(env_data));
    luasql_setmeta (L, LUASQL_ENVIRONMENT_OCI8);
    /* fill in structure */
    env->closed = 0;
    env->conn_counter = 0;
    env->envhp = NULL;
    env->errhp = NULL;
/* maybe OCI_SHARED and OCI_THREADED ??? */
    if (OCIEnvCreate ( &(env->envhp), (ub4)OCI_DEFAULT, (dvoid *)0,
            (dvoid * (*)(dvoid *, size_t)) 0,
            (dvoid * (*)(dvoid *, dvoid *, size_t)) 0,
            (void (*)(dvoid *, dvoid *)) 0,
            (size_t) 0,
            (dvoid **) 0))
        luasql_faildirect (L, "couldn't create environment");
    /* error handler */
    ASSERT (L, OCIHandleAlloc((dvoid *) env->envhp,
        (dvoid **) &(env->errhp), /* !!! */
        (ub4) OCI_HTYPE_ERROR, (size_t) 0, (dvoid **) 0), env->errhp);
    return 1;
}


/*
** Create metatables for each class of object.
*/
static void create_metatables (lua_State *L) {
    struct luaL_Reg environment_methods[] = {
        {"__gc", env_close}, /* Should this method be changed? */
        {"close", env_close},
        {"connect", env_connect},
        {NULL, NULL},
    };
    struct luaL_Reg connection_methods[] = {
        {"__gc", conn_close}, /* Should this method be changed? */
        {"close", conn_close},
        {"execute", conn_execute}, 
        {"commit", conn_commit},
        {"rollback", conn_rollback},
        {"setautocommit", conn_setautocommit},
        {NULL, NULL},
    };
    struct luaL_Reg cursor_methods[] = {
        {"__gc", cur_close}, /* Should this method be changed? */
        {"close", cur_close},
        {"getcolnames", cur_getcolnames},
        {"getcoltypes", cur_getcoltypes},
        {"fetch", cur_fetch},
        {"numrows", cur_numrows},
        {NULL, NULL},
    };
    luasql_createmeta (L, LUASQL_ENVIRONMENT_OCI8, environment_methods);
    luasql_createmeta (L, LUASQL_CONNECTION_OCI8, connection_methods);
    luasql_createmeta (L, LUASQL_CURSOR_OCI8, cursor_methods);
    lua_pop (L, 3);
}


/*
** Creates the metatables for the objects and registers the
** driver open method.
*/
LUASQL_API int luaopen_luasql_oci8 (lua_State *L) {
    struct luaL_Reg driver[] = {
        {"oci8", create_environment},
        {NULL, NULL},
    };
    create_metatables (L);
    lua_newtable (L);
    luaL_setfuncs (L, driver, 0);
    luasql_set_info (L);
    return 1;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It is not a function. It is a macro defined in your code:

```
int checkerr (lua_State *L, sword status, OCIError *errhp);
#define ASSERT(L,exp,err) {sword s = exp; if (s) return checkerr (L, s, err);}
```

So the first one is Lua state, second one some expression to evaluate and the last one is returned error.